# I am getting the run time error with the following code in SPOJ,Language C, compiler gcc 4.3.2 Code is:

Tags: c, gcc, runtime-error

The following is the code, which shows run time error. This program reads the numbers from key board until the number 42 is entered and displays all the numbers read from the key board except 42.

```
#include<stdio.h> 
int main(void) 
{   
    int array[1000];   
    int counter=0;   
    int i;   
    while(1)   
    {     
        scanf("%d",&array[counter]);     
        if(array[counter++]==42) break;   
    }   
    for(i=0;i<counter;i++) 
        printf("%d\n",array[i]); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are getting this error because of having fixed array size input of maximum 1000.

Probably, the test case might be having input size more than 1000,say 1200 or something in which your code will not work. Hence,in that case it is giving you runtime error as your code is not validating those specific those test-cases!!!

Please try storing inputs using dynamic memory allocation,i.e,using `malloc`,etc!

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int size = 1000;
    int counter=0;
    int i;
    int *array = malloc(size * sizeof(*array));
    if (array == NULL)
    {
        printf("malloc error\n");
        return -1;
    }
    do
    {
        if (counter==size)
        {
            size *= 2;
            int *tmp = realloc(array, size * sizeof(*array));
            if (tmp == NULL)
            {
                printf("realloc error\n");
                break;
            }
            array = tmp;
        }
    } while((scanf("%d",&array[counter]) == 1) && (array[counter++]!=42));
    for(i=0;i<counter-1;i++)
        printf("%d\n",array[i]);
    free(array);
}
```

this should solve your problem. if there is too less space available, the `realloc` will double the available space.

Answer (score 0):

Your code actually has *less* bugs than some of the answers you have been given. There are two **major** problems with your code:

1. You **must** check that `counter` doesn't grow larger than your array size. Eg:

   ```
   while (counter < 1000)
     ...
   ```
2. You **must** check the return value of `scanf()`. The `scanf()` function return the number of input items successfully assigned (**`0`** or **`1`** in your case), *or* the value of **`EOF`** if it runs out of input. If the user enters a letter, or send a *End-of-Input* signal to the command interpreter, your program will enter an infinite loop. You need to break out of the loop in this case:

   ```
   if (scanf("%d",&array[counter]) != 1)
     break;
   ```

   A more thorough solution would distinguish between the two error conditions and present the user with meaningful error messages.